# AWS ELB not configuring properly with EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, apache-2.4, amazon-elb, opsworks

I have a working EC2 instance I'd like to place, along with a copy, behind an Elastic Load Balancer, but I can't get it to work.

ELB Settings:

- **Ports:** ELB HTTP:80 -> EC2 HTTP:80, default VPC
- **Security groups:** AWS-OpsWorks-LB-Server
- **Health Check:** HTTP, 80, /
- **EC2 Instance:** My working EC2 instance

Hitting the ELB directly returns a 503 error code.

Digging into the Apache logs of my EC2 instance, I see:

```
x.x.x.xx - - [18/Feb/2016:14:21:18 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 52 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/1.0"
```

The ELB health check is returning 400, Bad Request, but pretty sure the "/" path is correct as I have a working Drupal instance in /var/www/html.

I don't think the problem is the security groups either, since if I use the exact same ELB, as is, and fire up a new EC2 instance as a PHP App Server via AWS OpsWorks, the ELB works fine.

I'm assuming I must be missing some package or configuration but looking over the Chef 11 recipes AWS uses to build a PHP App Server it's hard to see what I've forgotten.

Thoughts?

Comment: On that instance itself, what do you see if you run this command: `curl -kv http://127.0.0.1/`?

Comment: "HTTP 1.1/400 Bad Request...The provided host name is not valid for this server.". Maybe related to a Drupal 8 security mechanism outlined [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/145286/what-does-the-provided-host-name-is-not-valid-for-this-server-mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, solved this -- well, at least got it working without knowing exactly the underlying cause. Thanks to [TJ Saunders](https://serverfault.com/users/253490/tj-saunders) for pointing me in the right direction.

For whatever reason the AWS GUI wizard did *not* register the instance, despite the step-by-step, browser-based creation process suggest that it did. Instead from my EC2 instance I entered:

```
aws elb register-instances-with-load-balancer --load-balancer-name my-elbs-name --instances my-ec2-instance-id
```

And then it worked.